# UPDATE a large set of rows based on a list of IDs in a file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a file with rather large list (160 000) of IDs (`bigint`) which are used for clustered index. For each of these I need to update two `bit` columns. My first trial was via C# script in LinqPad which translates into SQL. To illustrate what I am trying to achieve:

```
var reports = File.ReadAllText((@"C:\list.txt")).Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
reports
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(r => {
            var row = DatabaseRecords.First(u => u.UserUsageId == long.Parse(r));
            
            row.IsYummy = true;
            row.isJuicy = true;
            
            SubmitChanges();
    });
```

but it is far from what I need in terms of performance and I want do it in SQL itself, but can't come up with a more performant way to do so.

I was thinking about somehow filling a temporary table and then perform a select from it within an update clause?

EDIT: Here is the execution plan:[image]

Comment: Show us your SQL and the execution plan if you want performance advice. There is no point showing us C# is you want a SQL solution.

Comment: I added both. Although the SQL is just a trivial UPDATE done many times per minute.

Comment: Use "Paste The Plan" for your execution plan so we can inspect it fully.

Comment: Can't see your SQL?

Comment: I don't see "Past the plan" option anywhere. The one I posted is pertaining my query.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Is this a one-off or infrequent manual operation? If so, I would suggest just importing the ID list into a staging table something like `StagedIdList(Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY)` and then perform a single update using a join - `UPDATE D SET IsX = 1, IsY = 1 FROM StagedIdList S JOIN Data D ON D.UserUsageId = S.Id WHERE (IsX = 0 OR IsY = 0)`. Alternately, you could (1) paste the data inline into a SQL script `DECLARE @List VARCHAR(MAX) = '<multiline data here>'`, (2) use `REPLACE()`, `SPLIT_STRING()`, and `TRY_CAST()` to parse the data into a temp table, and (3) apply the above update.

Comment: See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eZP4U8_b) for a sample of the paste, split, parse and update technique.

Comment: If you don't wanna mess with bulk imports, create a long json string of [12345, 567890... ] numbers, and then build an update using OPENJSON, something like: `UPDATE t SET flag = 1, flag = 2 FROM yourtable t INNER JOIN OPENJSON('[12345,567890...]') with (id BIGINT '$') x ON x.ID = t.someID` and just execute that sql string

Comment: Other solution can be in C# put the IDS in array,in Proc create proc  as UserDefine Table type as parameter.Now in C# array you can apply pagination in array,fill UserDefine Table with 10000,5000 or evem more or less number of  ids depending upon performance and pass to proc.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting the ID's into some temp table and running an update statement from that would be the quickest - doing it all in SQL rather than C#

But, if that is not an option, you can try updating in parallel?

```
    var reports = File.ReadAllText((@"C:\list.txt")).Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
reports
    .ToList()
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(r =>
    {
        var row = DatabaseRecords.First(u => u.UserUsageId == long.Parse(r));

        row.IsYummy = true;
        row.isJuicy = true;

        SubmitChanges();
    });
```

You can also try optimizing your code - not sure if this will work or if it will be faster (my EF is a bit rusty):

```
    DatabaseRecords
    .Where(u => reports.Exists(r => r == u.UserUsageId))  // rather get all the rows you need to update in one go
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(row =>
        {
            row.IsYummy = row.isJuicy = true;
            SubmitChanges();  //  not sure, but think you only need to run this once, after all records have been set;
        }
    );

//SubmitChanges();   // here maybe?
```